# Python list to str and backwards

Tags: python, converters

can anyone help me with this convertion? I need a list from string.

```
x = [[1,2],[2.3,59]]
y = str(x)

backToList = list(y) 
backToList = ['[', '[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '2', '.', '3', ',', ' ', '5', '9', ']', ']']
```

I need to get this: **backToList = [[1,2],[2.3,59]]**
Thx.

Comment: you can use `eval(y)`

Comment: typical `eval` case. As the example says, use the `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `ast.literal_eval` for this, which is safer than `eval`:

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[2.3,59]]
>>> y = str(x)
>>>
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(y)
[[1, 2], [2.3, 59]]
```

Comment: Thx, why is that safer?

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper In this case it doesn't make a difference, but `eval` has many vulnerabilities that can be exploited if executed on user input. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html